# CSS Specificity Issue - Why is this selector taking priority?

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-specificity

***Edit:***

**After reviewing my css, I realized I had a giant hole in my head and the actual issue was the simple fact that I hadn't defined a `color` rule in `bar.css` `.footer-link:hover`, so clearly the color rule from `foo.css` `a:hover` was being applied. CSS 101. Thank goodness it's Friday. I obviously need the weekend. Thanks for your help!**

I'm seeing something interesting while working on some UI for a project, and I'm sure it's related to my lack of understanding surrounding CSS specificity. I've done some research and still can't seem to solve my own problem.

Anyway, I have several defined styles for anchor elements contained in two different stylesheets. For simplicity, I'll call them `foo.css` and `bar.css`. `foo.css` is included in the page before `bar.css`

In `foo.css` there are the following rules:

```
a {
    color: #0088cc;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    color: #0088cc;
}
```

In `bar.css` there are the following rules:

```
.footer-link {
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: rgb(150, 150, 150);
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 18px;
    margin-right: 6px;
}

.footer-link:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255, 191, 254, 0.8);
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

The HTML markup is:

```
<a href = "#" class = "footer-link">Cheese is really good</a>
```

It seems that the `hover` styles are being applied from `foo.css` even though, as I understand it, `.footer-link:hover` has a higher specificity. The normal anchor styles are being applied as I would expect.

So my question is:

Why is the hover rule getting applied in `foo.css` even though `bar.css` is included later in the page and `.footer-link:hover` should be a higher specificity than `a:hover`?

Thanks in advance!

[**Example on jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cfqXa/)

Comment: your jsFiddle works the way I would expect in Firefox, pink background with blue text on hover.  The order in which CSS styles are defined is only relevant when they have the same "score", in which case, last in wins.  In your case, the `.footer-link:hover` has a higher score than `a:hover`, so the order in which you write them is irrelevant.

Comment: from the jsfiddle you provided, bar.css works over foo.css

Comment: Works as expected in chrome too.

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both styles are being applied.  You are correct that `.footer-link:hover` is more specific than `a:hover`, but what you are seeing is a combination of both style definitions.  This is the cascading part of cascading style sheets.

Your `a` and `a:hover` styles are applied first, then the higher specificity `.footer-link` and `.footer-link:hover` styles are applied afterwards, and any of their explicitly defined properties (such as `background`) overwrite the previous definitions.

However, since you don't specify the link `color` in the `.footer-link:hover` style, it inherits the property from `a:hover` instead.

The specificity here is working exactly as it's supposed to, you're just a bit confused about how inheritance and specificity work!

Answer (score 2):

It is possible and normal for multiple rule sets to apply to an element. First `a:hover` applies a `color`, and then `.footer-link:hover` applies a `background-color` and `text-decoration`. If they had conflicting styles, then the styles of `.footer-link:hover` would win – but no styles conflict. So the styles from the two rule sets just combine.

If you don’t want the `color` from `a:hover` to apply, you should reverse it by setting `color: #0088cc` again in `.footer-link:hover`.

Answer (score 1):

The properties set by the selectors are different, but both match, so both of them are applied. If `bar.css` had a `color` property set in the block in question, it would override the one in `foo.css`, because the class selector `.footer-link:hover` (priority 0,0,2,0) is more specific than the element selector `a:hover` (priority 0,0,1,1). This is also what you must do here: in `bar.css`, change the later block to

```
.footer-link:hover {

    /* the new line */
    color: <whatever should be the color of .footer-link when hovering>

    background-color: rgba(255, 191, 254, 0.8);
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

(I believe you want `rgb(150, 150, 150)` in the current situation.)